# Can not pull nanoserver:1903 Docker image

Tags: windows, docker, nano-server

I would like to pull the nanoserver:1903

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1903
```

The command line for this is copied from the [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-nanoserver),
That page also say, **this image is created 2 weeks ago: 05/22/2019**

When I execute the pull command I got the error message.

> 1903: Pulling from windows/nanoserver
>   no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries

**What am I missing?**

I am on Windows 10, some additional diag info:

> Swarm: inactive
>   Default Isolation: hyperv
>   Kernel Version: 10.0 17763 (17763.1.amd64fre.rs5_release.180914-1434)
>   Operating System: Windows 10 Pro Version 1809 (OS Build 17763.404)
>   OSType: windows
>   Architecture: x86_64
>   CPUs: 28
>   Total Memory: 63.69GiB
>   Debug Mode (client): false
>   Debug Mode (server): true
>   Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
>   Experimental: true

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First check if your Docker is switched to run Windows containers. Now, check your windows version by typing `winver` on run. For e.g. in my case it's `1607`. Pull the corresponding tag for e.g. `docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1607`. Basically, the version/tag of image being pulled *must* match the version of Windows running on the system.

Comment: Thx. Both information is in my original post (yes I am switched to Windows containers, and my version is 1809), see the quoted yellow diag info. It is not clear that this operating system version match applies just for nanoserver? (Because I can pull the image mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019 with no problem.)

Comment: @g.pickardou It is not clear that this operating system version match applies just for nanoserver - i think so but not sure. in your case, windows version is 1809. So docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809 will work

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer did not work for me but I stumbled across it. I hope it helps someone.

I got:

> docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:ltsc2022
> ltsc2022: Pulling from windows/nanoserver
> no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.19045 in the manifest list entries

I went back to 2019 which is the previous version. This worked.

> docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:ltsc2019